# Gemfile.lock Error while trying to deploy RoR application on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, gemfile.lock

I am getting the following error on the server while deploying my application

```
The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

I have already checked in the Gemfile.lock into my code repository.

Can anyone please guide me on what to do for this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Gemfile.lock is actually checked out during deployment.

For example check that it is not listed in any `.gitignore` files.

Hope that helps!